# How to find the minimum area rectangle in C# using OpenCVSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, image-processing

I need to extract a black/white image (signature) from within a white bitmap canvas and resize it to specific dimensions.  The image (sig) is guaranteed to be black on a white background.

The reason is that when we capture the signature, some people write tiny, other fill the capture area. However, I need them all to end up to fill the edges of another image for further processing.

I need to find the X/Y coordinates / rectangle boundary of the signature so I can extract just that portion of the canvas, and not end up with lots of surrounding white space.

I noticed this in a different project, and want to know how to implement in OpenCVSharp.

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Minimum_Area_Rectangle_in_CSharp

thanks.

Comment: I assume that opencvsharp is just a c# wrrapper to opencv. If so, just call whatever function wraps cv::minAreaRect().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: As pointed out by Miki in the comments, you may be searching for the rotated box.  You probably want `OpenCvSharp.Cv.MinAreaRect2()`, which takes a `CvArr` of points, and returns a `CvBox2D`.

[Reference](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/tree/master/src/OpenCvSharp/Src/Core)

---

Bounding box calculations are relatively simple as long as you aren't worried about tilt in the bounding box, finding the minimum enclosing rectangle is just a matter of finding the smallest and largest x and y that correspond to a black pixel.  The simplest method would be something like:

```cs
// You would actually use your image
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(640,480);

// For the demonstration generate some randomized data
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    b.SetPixel(r.Next(200) + 50, r.Next(200) + 50, Color.Black);
}

int minX, minY;
int maxX, maxY;
minX = minY = int.MaxValue;
maxX = maxY = int.MinValue;

// Find the minimum and maximum black coordinates
for (int x = 0; x < b.Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < b.Height; y++)
    {
        if (b.GetPixel(x,y).ToArgb() == Color.Black.ToArgb())
        {
            if (x > maxX) maxX = x;
            if (x < minX) minX = x;
            if (y > maxY) maxY = y;
            if (y < minY) minY = y;
        }
    }
}

// Draw a bounding box for the demonstration
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
{
    Pen red = new Pen(Color.Red);
    g.DrawRectangle(red, minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
}

b.Save("c:\\tmp\\test.png");
```

This is admittedly not the cleanest implementation, but any algorithm for searching for a minimum and maximum will work. (You just have to do it for both dimensions.)

Comment: The OP is asking for min oriented bounding box. So you need also to compute convex hull and rotating calipers. Or just call the function that wraps cv::minAreaRect

Comment: I wasnt concerned about tilt so the bitmap search concept worked fine with a small bti of tweaking.
Many thanks theB !